# unable to transform pos constraints to odom_combined

Tags: ros, joint, odom-combined, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to change "move_arm_simple_pose_goal.cpp"
http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_arm/Tutorials/MoveArmPoseGoal

I wanted to specify pos and orientation and changed
desired_pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0 -> 0.5  (line31)

Then there's error message

[ERROR] [1311149512.607969220, 1281.101000000]: Unable to transform pose constraint on link 'r_wrist_roll_link' to frame 'odom_combined'
[ERROR] [1311149512.608135351, 1281.101000000]: Could not prepare planning environment

How can I fix it or change r_wrist_roll_joint's orientation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10654/unable-to-transform-pos-constraints-to-odom_combined/) by [ys](https://answers.ros.org/users/860/ys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to provide a proper quaternion. Just changing one value will obviously leave the quaternion unnormalized.

There are some convenience functions that create quaternions from roll,pitch,yaw depending on what you need.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ys](https://answers.ros.org/users/860/ys/) on 2011-07-20**:
Thank you so much.